# Incorrect line ending characters from Excel-generated .txt files not accepted by Gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot

I want to make a data file of 1000+ data points to `splot` with Gnuplot. However, Excel uses the CR line endings, while I can only get LF to work fully.

The Gnuplot command I use is simply `splot "data.txt" u 1:2:3 w l`.

As mentioned in the comments, I tried to use

```
splot '< tr "\r" "\n" < data.dat' u 1:2:3
```

This partly solved my problem; now at least some data points show up (Fig. 1), but the y-values are incorrect (all set to 1).

Also, I get the same results as in Fig. 1 if I copy the data contents into a text file on a linux system via ssh conncetion to a univeristy computer.

```
cat -v data.txt
```

(linux-generated text file) results in printing the data, while doing the same with the Excel generated text file gives:

```
1   1   3^M1    2   4^M1    3   5^M     ^M2 1   6^M2    2   7^M2    3
```

It should be

```
1 1 3
1 2 4
1 3 5

2 1 6
2 2 7
2 3 8
```

[image]

Fig. 1

Comment: does that .txt file contain field such as x y z?

Comment: First line is '# X Y Z'

Comment: It's working on mine when I save it to csv format with correct delimiter.

Comment: What is the correct delimited?

Comment: Use field delimiter as space and ignore text delimiter.

Comment: Not working. When I open the txt file with some texteditor, it looks just like when I made it manually: three columns separated by a single space, '.' as decimal sign.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109413/discussion-between-vusan-and-andersmb).

Comment: Please provide a sample of the data file so we can see what you are working with.  Please also provide the gnuplot commands you are running.  Without either of those, it is impossible to determine if the error is the datafile format, or the gnuplot commands you are running.

Comment: I compared one excel-generated .txt file with a manually generated one with Meld, and the only difference is the line ending. Gnuplot accepts LF, but excel generates either CR or CRLF. This is the issue. I am using excel for mac, and running Gnuplot on OSX.

Answer (score 0):

If the problem it's a file ending with CR, you can filter those by plotting through a pipe:

```
plot '< tr "\r" "\n" < data.dat'
```

On the other hand, I tested CRLF and gnuplot understands those.

p.s. That's a shame that excel uses CR: that was used on mac os 9...

Comment: I am using Version 5.0 and patchlevel 3 of Gnuplot, if that matters.

Comment: I'm sorry, but unless you show a minimal example (http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) it'a almost impossible to help. Post the script and the data